# Select all stores open at current time

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, logic

I have a table named opening_hours that look like this:

id int(11), weekday int(1), start_hour time, end_hour time

[image]

I use this query to select all stores that are open now:

```
SELECT * FROM shops s 
INNER JOIN opening_hours o 
ON ( s.id = o.id ) 
AND ( o.weekday = WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) + 1 ) 
AND ( ( CURTIME() >= o.start_hour ) AND ( CURTIME() <= o.end_hour ) )
```

My problem is that this query is giving the wrong result when stores are open after midnight. That's because time after midnight is earlier than the time before midnight. How to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct logic is more complicated.  When the opening hours span two dates, then in the wee hours of the morning, you have to look at the *previous* days opening hours -- unless you assume that the hours are the same for each day (but then why have table?).

The condition is more like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM shops s INNER JOIN
     opening_hours o 
     ON s.id = o.id
WHERE ((o.weekday = weekday(curdate()) + 1) and
       ((o.end_hour > o.start_hour and curtime() >= o.start_hour and curtime <= o.end_hour) or
        (o.end_hour < o.start_hour and curtime() >= o.start_hour)
       ) or
      (o.weekday = weekday(date_add(curdate(), interval 1 day))  + 1 and
       o.end_hour < o.start_hour and
       curtime() <= o.end_Hour
      );
```

The three conditions are:

- Opening hours all in one day
- Opening hours span two days, and the hour not earlier than the opening
- Opening hours span two days, and the hour is earlier than the closing hour

Comment: Thanks a lot Gordon! But can you please explain how the accepted answer fail? I do not understand why your answer works better.

Comment: @Droabs . . . The accepts answer fails because an entry such as "Monday, 10:00 a.m. - 2: a.m.", is checking the *Tuesday* record for 1:00 a.m. on Tuesday.  It is not checking the *Monday* record.  The date comparison also needs to be adjusted for hours after midnight (and there might be an off-by-one error in the date comparison in this query).

Comment: Thanks! This solution does not work if opening hour is "5:00 am - 1:00 am" every week day.

Answer (score 2):

When the `end_hour` is less than `start_hour` then you have to modify the `end_hour` so that it becomes greater than `start_hour`.

One way to achieve this is to deduct `end_hour` from `24:00:00` when `end_hour` is less than `start_hour` otherwise `end_hour` prevails.

```
SELECT * FROM shops s 
INNER JOIN opening_hours o 
ON ( s.id = o.id ) 
AND ( o.weekday = WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) + 1 ) 
AND ( ( CURTIME() >= o.start_hour ) AND ( CURTIME() <= IF(o.end_hour < o.start_hour,TIMEDIFF(TIME('24:00:00'),o.end_hour),o.end_hour ) ) ) ;
```

**EDIT:**
The query above performs great when the `end_hour` is `00:00:00`.

But it might give wrong output for this case

`start_hour = 07:00:00 & end_hour = 02:00:00`.

So, here how you can recover (use this condition in your main query):

```
AND 
( 
  IF(o.end_hour < o.start_hour, 
  ( CURTIME() >= o.start_hour ) OR ( CURTIME() <= o.end_hour ),
  ( CURTIME() >= o.start_hour ) AND ( CURTIME() <= o.end_hour )
)
```

Note that if the **range lies in the same date** then this condition should prevail:

`( CURTIME() >= o.start_hour ) AND ( CURTIME() <= o.end_hour )`.

And if the range **wraps over midnight** then this condition should be in action:

`( CURTIME() >= o.start_hour ) OR ( CURTIME() <= o.end_hour )`

Comment: That's great. Thanks a lot!